# Single word for distance and duration

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that defines the distance both in time and space between two points?

I am writing a long text and repeating distance and duration constantly seems weird.

I have considered gap but I am not sure if it makes sense.

I'd like to turn "The distance and duration for the jorney is 100km and 1 hour" into "The ____ for the journey is 100km and 1hour".

Comment: Would you accept a rather nondescript word such as "length"?

Comment: Seems like there should be an easy way to avoid the issue completely because once the distance is established the duration depends on speed. I mean, as it stands, it's just a different way of saying "The journey is 100 km, and we are traveling at 100 km/h". The common phrase "the trip takes an hour" is based on assumed knowledge like highway speeds.

Comment: I think regardless of the word (or lack of word) you use, you should use __or__, instead of __and__, to avoid the impression that you go 100 km, then travel an additional hour: _The journey is 100 km, __or__ 1 hour_.

Comment: You're using a distance metaphor to speak of duration; that's one of the major ways English handles time reference (the other is [by using a commercial transaction metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf)). If you acknowledge that, you can build a consistent referential structure; but looking for words at random is unlikely to help.

Comment: If you were a physicist you could use [spacetime interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval),

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a word, you could use [**measure**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measure):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 d (1)** : a measured quantity
>   **1 d (2)** : amount, degree
>   // giving children a greater *measure* of freedom

In the case of the example sentence:

> The *measure* of the journey is 100km and 1 hour.

---

Note, however, that that while this is correct, it sounds somewhat old-fashioned. As was added in a comment under the question, you could simply not use a word at all:

> The <s>measure of the</s> journey is 100 km and (takes) 1 hour.

Comment: In the last sentence, I'd use "takes" rather than "is".

Answer (score 1):

"Length"

Merriam Webster: a measured distance or dimension OR duration or extent in time

Answer (score 0):

The distance might be marked on the ground but when you are running or moving by car or whatever, each metre or kilometre is measure of the duration of changing distance.
Just like seconds and hours, these are measures of duration of the motion itself.
So really it is the word duration you are looking for in your sentence. It is a duration of changing distance and motion, it seems to me.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary definition of duration that includes a measure of distance rather than just time?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to convey the same information is to invert the sentence and use something like "away" or "from here":

*The destination is 100km or 1 hour away.*

*The destination is 100km or 1 hour from here.*

In cities with lots of traffic, for example, it is very common to answer questions of the form "how far away is X?" in units of time: "it's about 20 minutes".

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the specific context you have, there are a number of words that could apply to both the duration (in time) and the distance (in space) of an event. They are all applicable to both time and space. At least these may give you some other/better ideas. You might try:

1. **extent** - *"The range, magnitude, or distance over which a thing extends"*
2. **long haul** - *"A long distance or a long period of time"*
3. **marathon** - *"An event or activity that requires prolonged effort, endurance, or attention"*

[TFD - extent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/extent)

[TFD - long haul](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/long+haul)

[TFD - marathon](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/marathon)